# Manage read scale-out setting in Azure Portal

Tags: sql-server, azure, high-availability, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm trying to see the current setting for read-scale out in the Azure Portal.

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out?view=azuresql#azure-portal) says:

> You can manage the read scale-out setting on the Configure database
> blade.

I'm unable to find any "Configure" option in the menu on the left in the SQL Managed Instance, or for individual DBs.

This is what I have available:

[image]

Where can I find this option?

The pricing tier for the SQL Managed Instance is:

> Business Critical Standard-series (Gen 5) (2048 GB, 24 vCores,
> Geo-redundant backup storage)

Comment: The read scale-out radio button appears on the pricing tier page. I only see it when selecting business critical SKU for VCore - not standard (though this is for SQL Database not managed instance)

Comment: Seems clear from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out?view=azuresql that same applies to managed instance

Comment: I updated the question, I'm actually using Business Critical Standard-series.
Can you provide a screenshot? I can't see that option.

Comment: I don't use managed instance and don't fancy provisioning one to provide a screenshot. For SQL database it appears here https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLM7c.png but only when a compatible service tier is selected

Answer (score 0):

**Read scale-out** is enabled by default on Premium, Business Critical, and Hyperscale service tiers. For Hyperscale, one secondary replica is created by default for new databases. Read scale-out cannot be enabled in Basic, Standard, or General Purpose service tiers. Read scale-out is automatically disabled on Hyperscale databases configured with zero replicas.

Refer official document: [Use read-only replicas to offload read-only query workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out?view=azuresql)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't answer my question. Just because something is enabled by default doesn't mean you can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't located under the "*Configure*" blade. You can manage the **read scale-out setting** in the "*Compute + Storage*" blade - but only if you are on Premium, Business Critical or Hyperscale service tiers.